# Make "the matrix" Run for a few seconds?

Tags: batch-file

I have this code:

```
:SET
@echo %random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%

goto :SET
```

but how do I make it so it only runs for a few seconds? And how would I change this variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I get `%TIME%` as current time and parsed it to get the current second. I did it on each iteration of your loop. If the desired time has not spent on the loop, (defined as `loopDuration`) then continue the next iteration.

```
echo off

:: Set your loop duration
set /a loopDuration=2

:: Get starting second
set "startingTime=%TIME:~6,2%"
set /a startingTime=%startingTime%

:SET

    echo %random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%

    :: Get current second
    set "currentTime=%TIME:~6,2%"
    set /a currentTime=%currentTime%

    if %currentTime% lss %startingTime% (
        set /a currentTime=%currentTime% += 60
    )

    set /a timePassed=%currentTime%-%startingTime% 

:: If desired time has not passed, continue the loop
if not %timePassed% equ %loopDuration% (goto :SET)
```

**EDIT:**

I also checked a special case here thanks to Stephan. In this case, if startingTime has the value of 59 or something close to 60, it is very likely that currentTime will have a value less than startingTime. I checked it with a simple if statement:

```
if %currentTime% lss %startingTime% (
    set /a currentTime=%currentTime%+=60
)
```

So there is no possibility that currentTime would be less than startingTime. Unless you want your loop to run more than 59 seconds.

Comment: try this with a time of `xx:xx:59`... that's going to be two very long seconds.

Comment: Hi where could I put the time in the script? Thanks loved your answer!

Comment: @Cool841 the time in seconds is in the variable `%loopDuration%`. Note that this will only work with time less than 60 seconds (which seems to perfectly fit your requirements)

Comment: @Stephan Thank you so much but how bout if I wanted to pause it for a second and then continue it?